# Many thumbnails fail to be generated in Nautilus, but OK in Dolphin with ffmpegthumbs

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails, wmv

It happens to lots of .wmv extension files, this is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: "I have tried to censor what should be censored." Um, I think you missed one.

Comment: Julian , you may have forgotten to pixelate one of the files there in the image.   I'm going to edit your post and remove that for now. Once you have safe-for-work image , please edit that into your post. Thanks !

Comment: If you watched close enough, you would see it is already censored.

Comment: Here is the new image.

Comment: @JulianLai   It may censor the private parts, but it still is suggestive. And I think community and moderators will agree with me, or at least you could provide a link to the image, instead of posting the full image into the post.  In any case, I see you rolled back my edit - that's up to you , but you have been warned. If moderator sees this post, they'll nuke it without questions and won't be as generous as I am :)

Comment: I found another way to censor it, it should be safe now.

Comment: In the Nautilus -> Edit -> Preferences -> Preview tab, there is setting for which files can get thumbnail generated, for instance those smaller than 10 MB. Have you tried changing that setting ? Your files may be over the limit set in Nautilus

Comment: Oooookay now. Why don't you get a new screenshot from the ~/Public folder.  There is an innocuous video file there that should demonstrate the problem without raising other issues. Thanks.

Comment: Because other videos are fine to have the thumbnails, this is the only one which can be found on my computer, here is another image, it should be 100% safe now, because I believe that nobody can see the content.

Comment: @JulianLai have you tried my suggestion by the way ? Like I said those files may be constrained by size

Comment: I have tried that since the beginning, it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't happen to every .wmv video, just some of them.